# How to superimpose a synchronization pulse on a 12V DC power line

Tags: dc-dc-converter, modulation, isolated

I have a 12V DC to DC isolated converter powering a remote display.

The DCDC is connected to a 12V supply.

I would like to add a 1ms or so pulse on that every second that can be detected by the display unit that then has an exact tick.

Crazy idea maybe, but is it feasible?

Edit: I am concerned about the power supply side. How to get 12V plus say a 1V pulse on top of it? And then isolated. Or .5V or -1V. Total current is max 100mA.  The remote side I will be able to do figure out later. I do not expect that to be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I would approach this is to have the output of your isolated DC-DC converter feed the end device via a diode.  There is a bulk storage capacitor after the diode that feeds the end device.  You also have something that detects when the input voltage to the diode drops.

Obviously, the diode and bulk storage capacitor are located at the end device.

It's far easier to detect a voltage drop than it is to try and force sufficient current into the DC line to cause a voltage rise.

You would have something like an opto-isolator at the supply end that either interrupts the output of the DC-DC converter for s specific period **or** causes a voltage drop.  Either method can work but detecting a complete absence of voltage at the end device is probably easier.

The above is a simple approach that is already in common use in several types of devices.  But you are going to have to provide many more details before anything concrete can be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a 90-deg rotated "modulation" transformer can be used to modulate a pulse onto the DC line, provided the transformer can handle the DC current.

One winding is connected to the pulse source, or audio-tone source, the other winding is a pass-through/series for the +12V line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is feasible. See, for example, the "parasite power" capability of some of the Maxim Integrated one-wire products. The devil is in the details, of course, but you haven't given us any of the details.